# Make POST request with large file in body for PHP 5.5+

Tags: php, post, large-data

There is an API I need to work with from my PHP application. One endpoint receives a file to upload as a body of the POST request. The uploaded file can be rather huge (up to 25GB). The endpoint returns a simple JSON content with either `200 OK` or different other status codes.

Example request may look like this:

```
POST /api/upload HTTP/1.1
Host: <hostname>
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 26843545600
Connection: close

<raw file data up to 25 GB>
```

Basically, I need to write a method that will perform such request without killing the server.

I tried to find any reasonable implementation but, from what I can see, both cURL and non-cURL (`stream_context_create`) methods require *string* request body, which may exhaust server memory.

Is there any simple way to achieve this without writing [a separate socket transport layer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php)?

Comment: open a stream, then feed your file in smaller chunks to that stream.

Comment: Could you not use (s)ftp?

Comment: @MarcB Is it possible to combine it with `stream_context_create(['http'])`, not re-implementing protocol with sending/parsing headers, etc?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ In what sense?

Comment: once you've got a stream, it basically becomes a filehandle you can use with `fwrite()`, so you set up the http stream with whatever headers you need, then go into a loop `while($chunk = fread($bigfile_handle, $max_chunk_size)) { fwrite($stream_handle, $chunk); }`

Comment: @VisioN one use-case would be to notify the receiving end (assuming you have control of it) that the file/post-body is on the sFTP server and for the receiving end to get it from there, via sFTP

Comment: @MarcB I probably do something wrong here. Apparently I can't execute `fopen($url, 'a+', false, $context)` due to `HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections`.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I think it's even more complicated to achieve for the current scenario. Also, I don't see much difference between HTTP and (S)FTP solutions here, just only that there are more existing FTP libraries to reuse.

Comment: @MarcB I ended up with socket approach. HTTP streams didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no better options were found, I went for a default solution with [`fsockopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php).

Here is the full source code of the utility function that will perform an HTTP request with low memory consumption. As the `data` parameter it can accept `string`, `array` and [`SplFileInfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) object.

```
/**
 * Performs memory-safe HTTP request.
 *
 * @param string $url       Request URL, e.g. "https://example.com:23986/api/upload".
 * @param string $method    Request method, e.g. "GET", "POST", "PATCH", etc.
 * @param mixed $data       [optional] Data to pass with the request.
 * @param array $headers    [optional] Additional headers.
 *
 * @return string           Response body.
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
function request($url, $method, $data = null, array &$headers = []) {
    static $schemes = [
        'https' => ['ssl://', 443],
        'http'  => ['', 80],
    ];

    $u = parse_url($url);
    if (!isset($u['host']) || !isset($u['scheme']) || !isset($schemes[$u['scheme']])) {
        throw new Exception('URL parameter must be a valid URL.');
    }

    $scheme = $schemes[$u['scheme']];
    if (isset($u['port'])) {
        $scheme[1] = $u['port'];
    }

    $fp = @fsockopen($scheme[0] . $u['host'], $scheme[1], $errno, $errstr);
    if ($fp === false) {
        throw new Exception($errstr, $errno);
    }

    $uri = isset($u['path']) ? $u['path'] : '/';
    if (isset($u['query'])) {
        $uri .= '?' . $u['query'];
    }

    if (is_array($data)) {
        $data = http_build_query($data);
        $headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
        $headers['Content-Length'] = strlen($data);
    } elseif ($data instanceof SplFileInfo) {
        $headers['Content-Length'] = $data->getSize();
    }

    $headers['Host'] = $this->host;
    $headers['Connection'] = 'close';

    fwrite($fp, sprintf("%s /api%s HTTP/1.1\r\n", $method, $uri));
    foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
        fwrite($fp, $header . ': ' . $value . "\r\n");
    }
    fwrite($fp, "\r\n");

    if ($data instanceof SplFileInfo) {
        $fh = fopen($data->getPathname(), 'rb');
        while ($chunk = fread($fh, 4096)) {
            fwrite($fp, $chunk);
        }
        fclose($fh);
    } else {
        fwrite($fp, $data);
    }

    $response = '';
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $response .= fread($fp, 1024);
    }
    fclose($fp);

    if (false === $pos = strpos($response, "\r\n\r\n")) {
        throw new Exception('Bad server response body.');
    }

    $headers = explode("\r\n", substr($response, 0, $pos));
    if (!isset($headers[0]) || strpos($headers[0], 'HTTP/1.1 ')) {
        throw new Exception('Bad server response headers.');
    }

    return substr($response, $pos + 4);
}
```

Example usage:

```
$file = new SplFileObject('/path/to/file', 'rb');
$contents = request('https://example.com/api/upload', 'POST', $file, $headers);
if ($headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') {
    print $contents;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Why do you hard-code the HTTP version in your checks for OK status (eg: `$headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'`). Since there are multiple versions, wouldn't it be better to parse the string and extract the response code? By the way you would probably use `===`

Comment: @BeetleJuice I've provided this code just as an example. Of course you can add more advanced parsing of the first response header to correctly pick up the protocol version and response status. Regarding `===`, I don't think it matters too much, as strict identical comparison won't give different results if you compare non-empty strings.