# How to stream binary data from file to POST body in PHP

Tags: php, post, stream

I'm not a PHP expert so please excuse the lack of correct terminology. Here is some background: There is a service running somewhere on the web and I have to communicate with it via REST API. The API requires me to send binary data (more specifically a ZIP) via POST request. The response will return other binary data that is to be saved in a file.

Since the request data and the response data may be arbitrarily large, I want to stream or buffer the data while reading it from and saving it in a file. The request has to be done in PHP.

Below is a code snippet I use to perform the POST request and handle the response (nevermind missing error handling). As you can see I have two files: `"request-data"` is a file containing the data I like to POST, `"response-data"` is the file where I write the response.

```
$binaryRequestFile = fopen('request-data', 'rb');
$binaryResponseFile = fopen('response-data', 'wb');
$url = "http://some/url";

$headerStr .= "Content-Type: application/zip\r\n";
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => $headerStr,
        'follow_location' => false,
        'max_redirects' => 0,
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => stream_get_contents($binaryRequestFile),
        'ignore_errors' => true
    ),
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$responseData = fopen($url, false, false, $context);
while (!feof($responseData)) {
    if (fwrite($binaryResponseFile, fread($responseData, 4 * 1024)) === FALSE) {
        return null;
    }
}
fclose($responseData);
```

The code above works, but I'd rather not use `stream_get_contents` to read the whole request data into memory. Isn't there a way to stream the data directly into the request similar to what is done with the response? I prefer using built-in PHP functionality, no external modules or CURL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make POST request with large file in body for PHP 5.5+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38186956/make-post-request-with-large-file-in-body-for-php-5-5)

Comment: Thanks! This kind of works, although it has the opposite problem. It streams the request data, but loads the whole response data into memory. I can tweak it of course, but socket operations are very low level and I e.g. have to parse the response headers from the response. Isn't there like a "normal" way to do a HTTP request with streams on both ends?